# Class not found showing Php

Tags: php, path

My index.php file exist in `public_html/myapp/files` directory,And i am trying to use library which exist in same directory `public_html/myapp/files`. But I am getting error

> Class 'SightengineClient' not found in
>   /home/public_html/myapp/files/index.php on line 7

Where i am wrong ?
Here is my code

```
namespace Tests;
use SightengineClient;
$client = new SightengineClient('myapikey', 'secretkey');
$output = $client->check(['nudity'])->set_url('https://d3m9459r9kwism.cloudfront.net/img/examples/example7.jpg');
echo "<pre>";print_R($output);
```

Comment: where's your require/include?

Comment: are you using composer in your project ?

Comment: @MohammedYassineCHABLI : no , i just open my cpanel and upload the downloaded code from github

Comment: you have to include the file where the class SightengineClient is defined in your file. **use** keyword will not import the class definition

Comment: Try this `$client = new \SightengineClient('myapikey', 'secretkey');`

Comment: @MayankDudakiya: showing same error in error_log file

Answer (score 1):

Using the **use** kewyord will not include the class if you are not managing your project with composer(generating the autoload ) will you can require the file in this way :

```
require_once('path to SightengineClient file');

$t = new SightengineClient;
```

> Using require_once will ensure that you are include only one time the
>   file .